# Cannot install SUPEE 10572 patch on Magento CE 1.6.0.0

Tags: magento-1, patches, magento-1.6, supee-10752

Already removed SUPEE-10570v1 and install SUPEE-10570v2 but error in below files.

File app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/User.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 127.

File app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
Hunk #2 FAILED at 812.

Comment: same issue her. Did you find a solution?

Comment: No.  I think it is a bug..

Comment: I copied the files from an unpatched 1.6.1.0, and then it worked

Comment: I did the same but not working